# Ehrenfest's theorem on Gaussians

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Considering the free evolution of a Gaussian wave packet, is it possible to use Ehrenfest's theorem to determine the average value of momentum given that of position?

And I imply the simplified version of the theorem, namely $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\langle x \rangle = \frac{1}{m}\langle p \rangle$, where $x$ and $p$ are the position and momentum, respectively.

Comment: Yes. [Ehrenfest theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem)  is a general theorem which does not depend on the shape of the wavefunction. See its application to the operator position $X$  in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem#General_example).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply the Ehrenfest's theorem to determine the expectation value of momentum for a given position or to determine the expectation value of position for a given momentum for a Gaussian wave packet!